# Use XPath to create DOM-Nodes

Tags: java, dom, xpath

I'm using javax.xml.xpath to read nodes out of a XML-DOM and to create Java-Objects from the read data.
After changing the data of these objects and perhaps creating new objects, I would like to write them back to the XML-DOM.
So I was wondering if it is possible to use xpath to also **create** nodes at specific positions in the XML-DOM. I am not sure if xpath is designed to write to DOM because its a "Query"-Language. But on the other hand SQL is also a query-language and is able to write data to databases.

So my general question is: Is it possible to create DOM-Nodes with XPaths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you will need to use low-level DOM methods to create new nodes.

Are you sure you are using the right approach? Could the whole application be written more easily in XSLT? Even if you want to use a Java tree-based API, why DOM, which is so slow and unwieldy compared with subsequent tree models such as JDOM and XOM?

Comment: No, I am not sure, whether I am using the right approach. ;) But I dont understand your suggestion to use XSLT. Isnt it a language to transform XML-Docs to some other format like HTML? Or Can I use it to transform XML to Java-Classes?

Comment: Well, we don't know enough about your application, but for many applications the data never needs to go anywhere near Java - you can simplify the application greatly by using XML technogies end-to-end. It's sometimes called XRX (for some people that means XQuery rather than XSLT, but either is much better at handling XML than Java is).

Answer (score 0):

No that is not possible as far as I know. But the elements returned are 'live' which means any change made on them is directly reflected in the dom.